# How do I make multiple output connections in Automate?

Tags: automate

I'm using the [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en) app to adjust my screen brightness when the phone is charged as well as alert me when the battery is full.

[image]

From the above screenshot, I want to connect the `YES` from `When power source plugged in` to the `IN` of `When battery level >= 100`. But when I try to do it, the line that connects `When power source plugged in` to the `IN` of `Is screen brightness` gets broken. I can only connect either `Is screen brightness` **or** `When battery level >= 100`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: May I know why you're trying put all the blocks under one flow? You could setup another flow just for that notification part.

Comment: @Firelord I was thinking using multiple Flows eat up more resources so I'm trying to make it so it only runs off of one for optimization.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Fork` block.

Connect `YES` of your `when power source plugged in` to `IN` at the fork block. Then connect `Is screen brightness` to `OUT` and `When battery level >= 100` to `NEW` and it should work.